# AJAX method Jquery can't return data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, methods, return

I can't return the value of an ajax request in Jquery. Here's my code:

```
    function ajaxUniversal(datos, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
            valores: datos
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Datos recibidos: "+data)
            return data; //This does not returns the data
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

And if I add the return statement to the final:

```
function ajaxUniversal(datos, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
            valores: datos
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Datos recibidos: "+data)
            return data;
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return data;//This is the statement but not works
}
```

And I get this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
How can I return the data? Thank you. And sorry for my bad english but I speak spanish.

Comment: you could try adding the async:false option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax calls are asynchronous so you can not return value immediately from them. Instead they return a promise to return a value so what you can do is:

```
function ajaxUniversal(datos, url, callback) {
return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {
        valores: datos
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html"
});
}
```

And call it like this:

```
ajaxUniversal( datos, url, callback ).then( function(data){

     //manipulate data here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are asynchronous, therefore you cannot return data with them. If you want to use that data, you need to use a callback function instead.

```
function ajaxUniversal(datos, url, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
            valores: datos
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Datos recibidos: "+data)
            callback(data);
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            callback(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Elsewhere...

```
ajaxUniversal(someData, someUrl, function(data){
    // Do work with data here
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return the item cause it no longer exists. try to define it first, like this:

```
function ajaxUniversal(datos, url) {
    var returlVal;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: false, 
        data: {valores: datos},
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Datos recibidos: "+data)
            returlVal = data;
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            returlVal = false;
        }
    });
    return returlVal;
}
```

Comment: This will not work. `returlVal` will always return undefined, because `$.ajax` is asynchronous. It has not yet fetched the data needed by the time the `return` statement is encountered.

Comment: I already wrote this kind of code a few times, it does work.
you can try if u'd like. tho I like your idea as well. might be a better one

Comment: @sg.cc it works because LiranBo makes it synchronous (see the aysnc: false) but imo sg.cc's solution is better because the world of JS is frequently around the idea of callbacks

Comment: Thanks. `async:false` was not there when I commented.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, this is failing due to the request being asynchronous. You could either fix your code as they suggest, by handling it asynchronously, OR you can set your request to be synchronous using `async: false`.

```
function ajaxUniversal(datos, url) {
    var data;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: false,  // <---- this will cause the function to wait for a response
        data: {
            valores: datos
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Datos recibidos: "+data)
            data = data;
        }
    });
    return data;
}
```